# Devolver valores a Select con javascript, quitar poner opciones

Tags: javascript, html

Saludos
Tengo este codigo, el cual quita los option a todos los demas select cuando alguno lo selecciona primero. Pero ahora necesito devolver el valor para seleccionar otro.

Entre ellos, por ejemplo, si selecciono el 1 en cualquiera, desaparecera la opcion 1 en los restantes. Si selecciono otra opcion en este select, entonces reaparecera la opcion que quite a todos los restantes.

Les pido por favor me ayuden, de antemano gracias.

```js
$(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
  $(this).siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion AA</option>
 <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion BB</option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion CC</option>
 <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A cual select quieres devolver los valores ?

Comment: Entre Gracias por responder.
Entre ellos, por ejemplo, si selecciono el 1 en cualquiera, desaparecera el 1 en los restantes. Si selecciono otra opcion en este select, que devuelva la opcion que quite a todos los restantes.

Comment: Tal cual como esta, funciona correctamente, pero cuando uso una etiqueta "`<table>`", mas especificamente "`<td><option>algo</option></td>`" el script de jquery no funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes guardar los options originales en cada select con `data`:

```
$(this).data('original', $(this).html());
```

Y luego restaurarlo con

```
$(this).html($(this).data('original'));
```

```js
$(".sel").each(function() {
  // Al cargar el documento guardo las opciones originales
  $(this).data('original', $(this).html());
});
$(document).on('change', '.sel', function() {
  $('.sel').each(function() {
    // Restauro  todas las opciones para todos los elementos 
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $(this).html($(this).data('original'));
    $(this).val(valor);
  });
  
  $('.sel').each(function() { 
  // borro las opciones  que no están seleccionadas 
    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion AA</option>
 <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion BB</option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion CC</option>
 <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wooow Ali, tu codigo resuelve el asunto.
gracias por responder

Comment: Solo que cuando lo corro tal cual no me vuelve a poner las opciones. ¿Que sera?

Comment: A que te refieres? ten en cuenta que el código tiene dos partes, una donde _"salva"_ las opciones actuales y la otra parte es cuando restauras las opciones _guardadas_

Comment: Claro, y esta genial. Mas cuando selecciono algun otra opcion de selecct el valor del select anterior desaparece.

Comment: No entender, pero te ayudó?, como me dices: _"no me vuelve a poner las opciones"_ Si te ayudó marca la pregunta como solucionada.

Comment: ok, la cuestion es que, cuando selecciono un valor del primer select, funciona bien quitando ese valor de los select restantes. Pero al seleccionar otro valor en otro select, el primer select que manipule pierde su valor seleccionado. es por eso.

Comment: Ahh, recién entiendo, entonces también hay que salvar el valor antes de restaurar las opciones. Acabo de editar la respuesta.

Comment: @RobAmaya, acabo de actualizar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, sería algo como esto:

```js
$(document).on('change','.sel',function(){

  if($(this).hasClass('uno')){
      $(this).siblings().find('option[value]').removeAttr('disabled')
    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr('disabled', true);
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('dos')){
    
      $('.tres option[value]').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.tres option[value="'+$('.uno').val()+'"]').attr('disabled', true);
      $('.tres option[value="'+$('.dos').val()+'"]').attr('disabled', true);
     
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="sel uno">
  <option>Seleccion AA</option>
 <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel dos">
  <option>Seleccion BB</option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel tres">
  <option>Seleccion CC</option>
 <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Genial, mas ahora recupera los valores anteriores cuando no deberia en las selecciones anteriores. ¿(ö_ö)?

Comment: No entendí, pero creo que ya se que falla.

Comment: jeje, si. Osea que cuando tomo una opcion del segundo o tercer select, se recuperan opciones que no deberian haberse recuperdo, porque ya se habin seleccionado.

Comment: mmmm, ya se como me comprenderias mejor. a tu codigo, en el css colocale esto en lugar del display:none  borrale display none y colocale esto:   background-color: #c2c2c2;
Y veras como no desaparece la opcion. ;)

Comment: ...hey, yo no sabia que se podia editar lo de otras personas, bueno, ya puse gris en el CSS de un codigo en las respuestas para denotar que no se van las opciones, como sea igualmente les agradezco me respondan, poco a poco va tomando forma esto. :D

Comment: Creo que por ahí va, pero no esta bien en el caso del select 2

Comment: Ya le dí al clavo, espero y sea así lo que quieres hacer. Saludos!!!

Comment: Gracias Chicos, Son Geniales!

Comment: @JorgeMejia lo malo del `display:none` en los `option` es que no funciona en todos los navegadores, por ejemplo safari, yo también había pensado usar `$('option').hide();` y `$('option').show()`

Comment: Si, por eso aun da fallo en la seleccion.

Comment: Pues en lugar de ponerle el estilo puedes usar .attr('disabled', true); ese si es compatible con todos los navegadores ;) ya edité la respuesta. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

No funciona con tablas

```js
$(".sel").each(function() {
  $(this).data('original', $(this).html());
});
$(document).on('change', '.sel', function() {
  $('.sel').each(function() {

    var valor = $(this).val();
    $(this).html($(this).data('original'));
    $(this).val(valor);
  });

  $('.sel').each(function() {

    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
              <option>Seleccion AA</option>
             <option value="1">a</option>
              <option value="2">b</option>
              <option value="3">c</option>
            </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
              <option>Seleccion BB</option>
              <option value="1">a</option>
              <option value="2">b</option>
              <option value="3">c</option>
            </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="sel">
              <option>Seleccion CC</option>
             <option value="1">a</option>
              <option value="2">b</option>
              <option value="3">c</option>
            </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Jair, debes detallar más tu respuesta, casi parece más un comentario. ¿A qué te refieres con que no funciona con tablas? ¿cómo soluciona ese código el problema expuesto en la pregunta? Te recomiendo que leas [answer] para más información y consejos.