# como quitar OPTION ya seleccionados desde otros SELECT?

Tags: html, jquery, formularios

sucede que necesito tener varios conjuntos de SELECT con los mismos conjuntos de OPTION dentro, a lo que una persona pueda ir eligiendo por cada SELECT algun OPTION, y lo ideal es que los OPTION ya elegidos no aparezcan en los demás SELECT, ademas si se volvieran a des-seleccionar estos deberían restablecer el OPTION que habían quitado.

Esto ultimo es con lo que tengo problemas, como volver a hacer reaparecer el OPTION al des-selecionarlo, por que al seleccionar uno se oculta de los demás SELECT pero si des-seleccionas ese OPTION de algún SELECT, solo esta disponible para si mismo, en los demás SELECT ya no existe ese OPTION.

```
$(".sel").each(function() {
  // Al cargar el documento guardo las opciones originales
  $(this).data('original', $(this).html());
});
$(document).on('change', '.sel', function() {
  $('.sel').each(function() {
    // Restauro  todas las opciones para todos los elementos 
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $(this).html($(this).data('original'));
    $(this).val(valor);
  });
  
  $('.sel').each(function() { 
  // borro las opciones  que no están seleccionadas 
    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
  });

});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion AA</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion BB</option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Seleccion CC</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

esta codigo se basa en estas respuestas:

[Devolver valores a Select con javascript, quitar poner opciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80458/devolver-valores-a-select-con-javascript-quitar-poner-opciones)

[Eliminar options de distintos select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43803/eliminar-options-de-distintos-select)

agradezco a las respuestas originales pero pido ayuda para finalizar el objetivo original de la pregunta de manera completamente funcional.